# Creating a build job for liferay portlet in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-ide

I want to develope a simple liferay portlet, deploy it using maven and build job in CI (Jenkins). But I come to know that Liferay doesn't support Maven and they are still working on it. Can anyone suggest me how can I create a build job for my liferay portlet in jenkins.
Does anyone worked on this before.
Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins will handle [Ant](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Ant+Plugin) just fine as well. See the plugin for Ant page.

I see [this](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Maven+SDK), which you can try for Maven.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. Most of the collegues are using Maven as Build automation tool and as part of my project I also have to use Maven. Normally we can create a Maven project or Liferay project in Eclipse IDE but is it possible to create Maven Liferay portlet using Eclipse IDE?

Comment: Yes it is. Liferay now offers all the maven tooling for creating / packaging / deploying portlets. 
See http://www.liferay.com/web/mika.koivisto/blog/-/blogs/12322618 for a start. 
Maven artefacts are available from version 6.0.x.

Answer (score 0):

Liferay [does offer maven artifacts](https://www.liferay.com/web/mika.koivisto/blog/-/blogs/15470275) for the latest versions. The wiki article that Larry gave in his answer seems to be outdated - unless you're running an older version of Liferay. However, even for that you might want to try if it isn't available under the same location (but different version number) as the current release (see Mika's blog)

Comment: I am running Liferay 6.0 version. I guess it is the latest version available in the market and open source. I had gone through Mika's blog before posting the question here and It didnt help me much.

Comment: 6.1 is the current version. I believe that the artifacts have been around in 6.0 as well, but they got a lot more love and attention with the recent version